# How to clear a character pointer array in c ?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, shell, pointers

I am trying to implement a basic Unix Shell in C. My program stores the user's commands in an char ** args. Here is my problem :

When I ask the user for a command, e.x ls  , ls is stored in args[0]. Then I fork a child process and execute the command using execvp. Now the next time the user enters another command,  say ls again, its stored at args[1]. So I cant execute this command using execvp.

I don't want to iterate through the array looking for ls or 
for any other arguements because then the program will execute random arguments.

I need a way to empty my args so that I can rewrite args[1].

```
int main() {
    pid_t childPro;
    pid_t parentPro;
    int i,r,argCount,status,pipeCount,changeOut;
    char **args;

    while(1) {
        argCount=0; 
        printf("davedShell$ "); 
        args = getln(); 

if(argCount>=1) {
    //Creating a child process through fork 
    childPro =fork (); 

    if(childPro==0){
        printf("Child Process: %d successfully created\n",(int) getpid());
        execvp(args[0],args);  
    }
    else if (childPro == -1) {
        printf("Fork Failed- Exiting"); 
    exit(1); 
    }
    parentPro = wait(&status);
    }
```

Comment: Why not dispose of the current buffers?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean by “empty my args”? Why would you start at 1 the second time and not 0? This may be a problem with what `getln` does. Post complete code. As it is, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately getln() was predefined by my prof, I will try to repost. But take this example:  If I input ls, then ls is stored in args[0]. Then execvp[0] will execute ls. Then I go back up to the loop. If I input ls again, then the system will not print the required output because the second ls is stored at args[1], so execvp does not execute properly. I am sorry for the miscommunications.

Comment: Read about then use [memset(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html); it is in standard C.

Comment: If "the second command is stored at argv[1]," as you say, it is probably just that you fail to (re)set some counter/index to 0 before each new command. BTW, any (reasonably) complete shell you post here will just be *way* too long for anybody just marginally interested to read through. Do reduce your examples as much as possible to get them read. Besides, you'll notice the problem yourself most of the time, avoiding lost time and possible public embarrasment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you understood Getln() you could answer your own question, why not Getln(&args)? where is the memory allocated for args?. allocating memory for args within function and returning a pointer to memory has to be handled correctly other wise you may get pointer to stack or registers depending on target architecture